# How to proxy a keyboard though a Raspberry PI?

Tags: keyboard, proxy, events

I have a keyboard that is plugged into a Raspberry Pi and the Raspberry Pi is plugged into my Mac. The Raspberry Pi is configured to act as a [USB Keyboard](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/) and this is how my Mac sees the Raspberry Pi, as a simple keyboard.

What I want to do is, when I type into the keyboard a program running at the Raspberry PI will record the keystrokes for further analyses, and then it would write the same keystrokes to the "USB Keyboard" so my Mac would see the keystrokes.

My first thought was to use the Linux evdev to catch the keystrokes from the keyboard, I had success with that, but how can I direct the keystrokes to the USB Keyboard interface is still a mystery for me.

Evdev is a good approach or there is anything better to solve this problem? And how can I forward the keystrokes?

Comment: The page you linked has the source code and instructions for a working python script that sends some characters. It even has a table of codes. Just read on, it starts at point _4. Python Script_.